# Jquery click trigger speed Comparison

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have 2 `jquery` **functions** which does the same. i.e. **trigger** a `radio check` and `click event` when a `table data` is clicked.

**Function1:**

```
 $(document).on('click', 'td', function(e) {
     // Open dialog
     var chk = $(this).closest("td").find("input:radio").get(0);
     if (e.target != chk) {
         chk.checked = !chk.checked;
     }
     var chkid = $(this).closest("td").find("input:radio").attr("id");
     $("#" + chkid).click();
 });
```

**Function2:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("td").click(function(e) {
        var chk = $(this).closest("td").find("input:radio").get(0);
        if (e.target != chk) {
            chk.checked = !chk.checked;
        }
        var chkid = $(this).closest("td").find("input:radio").attr("id");
        $("#" + chkid).click();
    });
})
```

**Question:**
Why does the second function `trigger` the radio click after some lag of `4 5 seconds` and the first with relatively no delay? What difference is there is using **`document.onclick()`** and click within the **`document.ready()`** to make such huge difference??

Following is the rubric that i have where the click triggers when i click the span of td.

[image: The tabs of rubric i have where click triggers]

Comment: 4-5 secs or millisecs ? If secs then can you share a demo in fiddle or something?

Comment: its 3-4 seconds sometimes 5 seconds. If it was millisecs, it would have been okay

Comment: I think It's because it's call after Domain ready

Comment: a proper explanation would deserve upvotes. i know its something to do with dom tree since i have a large dom. And lots of jquery functions, to create and style the table data.

Comment: I suspect the function 2 is causing a high memory usage and blocking click events while the handlers are being bound.  How many tds are we talking about?  Does the lag still happen if you wait for about 30 seconds after the page has completely loaded?

Comment: yes the lag persists. i am creating tds as in rubric for evaluating one's performance using jquery functions, which has another tabs of rubric with tds.

Comment: What is the purpose of triggering `click` on the radio? And where is the event handler for those radios?

Comment: the event handler for the radio has mix of c# codebehind from where the jquery function is being executed, and the purpose of triggering click is because the css and rubrick score calculation has been embedded in the radio click :(. And, i am completely NOOB. I just want to know the difference between click embedded in document.ready and the actual document.onclick()